Can songs from BMI-affiliated authors be used in the EU under a direct license?
What follows is my own (partial and possibly mistaken) understanding of this issue. Please point out any errors on my part.
In the United States authors do not grant BMI or ASCAP exclusive rights, because of antitrust law. Affiliated authors, therefore, retain the ability to license songs directly.
Whenever authors grant direct licenses, BMI requires that they inform it, but the end user is no party to that agreement. If an author doesn't inform BMI of a direct license, this is a violation of contract (by the author) which doesn't affect the validity of the license itself.
In the EU, authors who are affiliated with collecting societies have the right to license songs directly for non-commercial uses, under conditions specified by the collecting society.
Collecting societies in the EU have agreements with BMI and collect fees on behalf of BMI.
Now to my question.
Suppose a US author is affiliated to BMI and licenses a song directly to a user in the EU.
Can the user use the song, under this direct license?
I'm interested in both commercial and non-commercial use cases. I'm also interested in the case in which the author has and hasn't informed BMI of the direct license.
In my specific case, the country of reference is Italy, which grants special powers to its SIAE collecting society (which works with BMI) and the license is a public Creative Commons license (which is a kind of direct license).
My theory is that, because the author never granted any exclusive rights to BMI, someone in the EU should be able to use songs under a direct license (from BMI-affiliated authors), regardless of any agreement between other parties, or the fact that EU collecting societies do receive exclusive rights.

The licence is valid
To summarise:

Party A gives an exclusive licence to Party B
Party A then gives a licence to Party C
What rights does Party B have against Party C?

None. There is no agreement between B and C that would empower B to take any action against C. The agreement between A and C is legally binding, despite being a breach of the agreement between A and B.
B's only recourse is to sue A for breach of contract. A has done damage to B by doing something they are contractually not allowed to do, but C is innocent of any wrongdoing.
An exclusive licence allows B to stand in A’s shoes to protect A’s copyright. However, C has not broken copyright law because they have A’s permission.
Now, if A had transferred the copyright itself to B, A would no longer have the power to licence the work to C.
If C had knowingly induced A into breaking their contract with B, then they may be liable under the doctrine of tortious interference.
If the order of entering the agreements were reversed, the breach would be the same.
If both licences were non-exclusive, there is no breach and everyone can use the work.

Thank you. In the first point, did you mean to say "non exclusive"? Licenses to BMI are non-exclusive (unlike those to SIAE, which are exclusive). An exclusive license would grant B the sole right to perform the licensed act and B would be considered the owner of that right during the term of the license.

@Aspie96 he wrote Non-exclusive only to create a situation where there is a wrong

@trish, Dale M wrote "an exclusive license", in which case I don't understand why B wouldn't have a claim against C (since he would be the owner of that right). If the license is not exclusive, then B would have no claim against C. My question is whether Dale M meant to say "non exclusive" instead.
